# Protect HTTP email API

Tags: javascript, rest, security, authentication

This is probably duplicate, but I'm new to the topic and don't even know how to find existing answers... So I'll happily accept a pointer to any question it duplicates.

I've built an HTTP API that accepts POST requests with a subject and a body and sends an email. Simple.

On the other hand, I'm building a contact form on a website that posts to this endpoint via axios.

How can I prevent users from reading the js code in the client and just sending a ton of emails to me?

Comment: You can't. On the client means that I can see that code that you intended for me to see. Sensitive data should always be stored on the server where I'm not able to see it. But can you be more specific as to **what** security issues you are looking at, besides looking at your JavaScript. What is in your JavaScript that you don't want us to see?

Comment: If you're trying to prevent spam, use ReCAPTCHA.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier He just wants to prevent users from automating it to spam him with tons of email.

Comment: @Barmar well, then ReCAPTCHA is indeed the answer. :)

Comment: But can't a malicious user still just call http://api?subject=you&body=suck&captcha=true a million times and I'm done?